# xml linq messagebox based on condition

Tags: c#, xml, linq, if-statement

Based on this xml

```
  <Reservation>
  <SeatEconomy>2</SeatEconomy>
  <SeatFirst>14</SeatFirst> 
  </Reservation>
```

How can I make a MessageBox appear based on particular condition? i.e. pseudocode:

```
  //case 1 Economy Class
   if(elementName==SeatEconomy) 
   MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Economy class assigned seat {0}",   
   name6.ToString()), "Results", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

  //case 2 First Class
  if(elementName==SeatFirst) 
   MessageBox.Show(string.Format("First class assigned seat {0}",   
   name6.ToString()), "Results", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
```

That's what I have done so far:

```
    XDocument info = XDocument.Load("reservation.xml");
    var result = from reservat in info.Descendants("Reservation")
                     let ep = reservat.Element("SeatEconomy")
                     select ep;
        var compare = result.FirstOrDefault();

    //how can I select SeatFirst and do comparison between SeatFirst 
      and SeatEconomy?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this :             var result = info.Descendants("Reservation").Select(x => new
            {
                economy = (int)x.Element("SeatEconomy"),
                first = (int)x.Element("SeatFirst")
            }).ToList();

Comment: @jdweng thank you for your reply. See updated answer.